# Javascript: Adding a page-breaker before an image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kinda new in javaScript, I have a documentation in HTML and I want to have a **break-page before every image**.

This is the code I've been trying:

```
<script>
@media print {
    .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }
}

if (document.querySelectorAll)
    var clsElements = document.querySelectorAll(".image");

for (var i=0, max=clsElements.length; i < max; i++) {
     <div class="pagebreak"> </div>
}
</script>
```

*(Defining page break, taking all images, looping through them and using the pagebreak)*

Anyone has any idea about how to make it detect the images and put the page-breakers?

**edit**: i've tried with ".image" and ".img"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is have the CSS rule like so:

```
@media print {
  .image {
    page-break-after: always ;
  }
}
```

There is no javascript needed! In this case all you want is have a page brake after every image. Which is a "style-only" task. You do not need to manipulate DOM for that.

Read more about [break-after CSS here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbreak-after)

**Why your code did not work:**
You have added Css `style` inside a `script` tag. That will never work.

Comment: Hi @caramba, I added it but not working.
Maybe it's not detecting the image as an image or maybe it is not affecting the html code?